# Table view cell expanding in IOS 7

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

I am developing an iOS application. I have used a table view. When the user clicks to any cell then the cell expands. But some cells are not expanding in iOS 7. Other versions run correctly. Below is the sample code. How can I correct it?

```
- (BOOL)cellIsSelected:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Return whether the cell at the specified index path is selected or not
    NSNumber *selectedIndex = [selectedIndexes objectForKey:indexPath];
    return selectedIndex == nil ? FALSE : [selectedIndex boolValue];
}


#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if([self cellIsSelected:indexPath])
        {
            return 111;
        }
        // Cell isn't selected so return single height
        return 41;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return  [self.filteredItineraries count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"FlightTracker";

    CellFlightTracker *cell = (CellFlightTracker *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];


    if(cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib=nil;

        nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CellFlightTracker" owner:self options:nil];

        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
     }




        if([self cellIsSelected:indexPath])
        {
            cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
        }else
        {
            cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor darkGrayColor];
        }


    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     if([self cellIsSelected:indexPath])
             cell.backgroundColor= [UIColor blackColor];
         else
             cell.backgroundColor= [UIColor darkGrayColor];
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:TRUE];

        // Toggle 'selected' state
        BOOL isSelected = ![self cellIsSelected:indexPath];

        // Store cell 'selected' state keyed on indexPath
        NSNumber *selectedIndex = [NSNumber numberWithBool:isSelected];
        [selectedIndexes setObject:selectedIndex forKey:indexPath];


        // This is where magic happens...
        [tableView1 beginUpdates];
        CellFlightTracker *selectedCell = (CellFlightTracker*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];



        if(selectedCell.lblDepartureAirportStatus.hidden)
            [selectedCell.lblDepartureAirportStatus setHidden:NO];
        else
            [selectedCell.lblDepartureAirportStatus setHidden:YES];


        [tableView1 endUpdates];
}
```

Comment: It'd be useful to see the implementation for cellIsSelected: ...

Comment: Just as a test, could you comment out `[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:TRUE]` or try replacing it with `[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO]`? I've had problems with stacked animations in table view cells.

Comment: @JefferyThomas I tried but not working :/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It would be better if you subclass and UITableViewCell and use the layoutSubviews to adjust when you adjust the size of the cell.

```
//In SMTableViewCell.h

@interface SMTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *statusLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *seeMoreButton;

//SMTableViewCell.m

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    CGRect labelFrame = self.statusLabel.frame;
    labelFrame.size.height = self.frame.size.height - 55.0f;
    self.statusLabel.frame = labelFrame;

    CGRect buttonFrame = self.seeMoreButton.frame;
    buttonFrame.origin.y = labelFrame.origin.y+labelFrame.size.height+10.0f;
    self.seeMoreButton.frame = buttonFrame;
}
```

Keep an array to store the selectedIndexPaths

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *selectedIndexPaths;
```

Calculate the height of the cell

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    BOOL isSelected = [self.selectedIndexPaths containsObject:indexPath];

    CGFloat maxHeight = MAXFLOAT;
    CGFloat minHeight = 40.0f;

    CGFloat constrainHeight = isSelected?maxHeight:minHeight;
    CGFloat constrainWidth  = tableView.frame.size.width - 20.0f;

    NSString *text       = self.items[indexPath.row];
    CGSize constrainSize = CGSizeMake(constrainWidth, constrainHeight);
    CGSize labelSize     = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0f]
                            constrainedToSize:constrainSize
                                lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByCharWrapping];

    return MAX(labelSize.height+75, 100.0f);

}
```

Initialize custom Show more TableViewCell

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

    SMTableViewCell *cell= (SMTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass([SMTableViewCell class])
                                             owner:nil
                                           options:nil] lastObject];
    }

    BOOL isSelected = [self.selectedIndexPaths containsObject:indexPath];
    cell.statusLabel.numberOfLines = isSelected?0:2;

    NSString *text = self.items[indexPath.row];
    cell.statusLabel.text = text;


    NSString *buttonTitle = isSelected?@"See Less":@"See More";
    [cell.seeMoreButton setTitle:buttonTitle forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.seeMoreButton addTarget:self action:@selector(seeMoreButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.seeMoreButton setTag:indexPath.row];

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    return cell;
}
```

Button click event method

```
- (void)seeMoreButtonPressed:(UIButton *)button
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:button.tag inSection:0];
    [self addOrRemoveSelectedIndexPath:indexPath];
}

- (void)addOrRemoveSelectedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (!self.selectedIndexPaths) {
        self.selectedIndexPaths = [NSMutableArray new];
    }

    BOOL containsIndexPath = [self.selectedIndexPaths containsObject:indexPath];

    if (containsIndexPath) {
        [self.selectedIndexPaths removeObject:indexPath];
    }else{
        [self.selectedIndexPaths addObject:indexPath];
    }

    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]
                     withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

}
```

Same Event is given if the cell is selected

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    [self addOrRemoveSelectedIndexPath:indexPath];

}
```

Sample [Demo project link.](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/35012982/Demo%20Projects/SeeMoreCell_V1.0.zip)

Comment: Thank you @Vivek, your code is working. But I dont understand What can I do :/

Comment: To fix the separators in iOS 8, [call super in layoutSubviews](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25947394/uitableview-displays-separator-at-wrong-position-in-ios8-for-some-cells) in SMTableViewCell.m