# UITableView displays separator at wrong position in iOS8 for some cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8

We have a UITableView and it was working fine for iOS7 but when I tried in the iOS8 simulator, I saw the cell separator was placed incorrectly for most cells. Strangely, some cells display the separator correctly.

See the attached image:

[image: UITableView with wrong separator... sometimes!]

I set the cell height this way:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 70.0f;
}
```

Do you know what's happening? Thanks!

EDIT:

A workaround I'm using in the meantime is to disable the separator...

```
    [tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
```

...and paint it myself in the cell view...

```
    UIView* separator = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, cellHeight-1, frame.size.width - 40, 1)];
    separator.layer.borderWidth = 1;
    separator.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor];
    [self addSubview:separator];
```

...but I'd like not to do it.

Comment: Although this should be working, can you try to set the rowHeight property on the TableView itself?

Comment: Thanks, but setting `rowHeight` doesn't change anything... :(

Comment: Are you using AutoLayout?

Comment: Nope, it's a UITableView built from code. I guess I can enable AutoLayout from code but I didn't.

Comment: Thanks for the question. I got exactly the same issue, separator off position in iOS 8 yet it was good in iOS 7. I'm using the same workaround as of now.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I had the same problem and here is how I solved it:

If you are using a custom cell for your table view and you have overridden layoutSubviews, you need to call it's superview's method at the beginning of the method:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    // Your implementation
}
```

Comment: well, wasted 1 hour on this, and I wanted to write "thanks!" and see I already thank you in 2014.

Comment: not working for me and even when i have xib for custom cell; when i change   accessory in xib it is also drawn at wrong place. Also the content view is not filling complete of its size and tableview

Comment: Dijam, thank you for your answer. It help to resolve a selected grey background color in UITableView when iOS 14 released.