# UITableView Row Separator Lines Not Behaving Correctly With Expanding Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am expanding my cells with the following code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    let originalHeight: CGFloat = 48.0
    let expandedHeight: CGFloat = 135
    let indexPath = indexPath
    if self.expandButtonTappedIndexPath != nil {
        if indexPath == self.expandButtonTappedIndexPath! {

            return expandedHeight
        } else {
            return originalHeight
        }
    } else {
        return originalHeight
    }
}
```

And

```
@IBAction func expandButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    switch self.expandButtonTappedIndexPath {
    case nil:
        self.expandButtonTappedIndexPath = indexPath
    default:
        if self.expandButtonTappedIndexPath! == indexPath {
            self.expandButtonTappedIndexPath = nil
        } else {
            self.expandButtonTappedIndexPath = indexPath
            //self.tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!, atScrollPosition: .Top, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is the picture of the problem:**

[image]

All my previous times in expanding my cell, I never had this problem of that separator line appearing there and not under the expanded cell. But for whatever reason this time, it's appearing and I have no idea how to put it under the expanded cell.

And the following is how I set up my cell in the MainStoryBoard:

[image]

Now, I've tried changing the original height and that causes that line to move around. But I want the original height to be 48.0 and I want the separator line to move to the bottom of the expanded cell not awkwardly in the middle.

Any suggestions on how to fix this problem? Thank you so much in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I apologize. I should have done more research. The answer is found here:
[UITableView displays separator at wrong position in iOS8 for some cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25947394/uitableview-displays-separator-at-wrong-position-in-ios8-for-some-cells)

I just have to call the super class in my `layoutSubviews()` function in my cell. I apologize like so:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
}
```