# How to create a UIPickerView selection in Swift such that the view expands to allow to add options?

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I want to create a selection view like the images, so that the UIPickerView appears for selection and disappears when 'Done' is clicked.

Is it possible to create this when using storyboards?

It would be great if you could share descriptive steps to achieve the same. A link to a tutorial will also be great.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Refer this link , and at the bottom there is a demo project link , see that link:
```

[Table view cell expanding in IOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19112153/table-view-cell-expanding-in-ios-7)